# Gdata URL given by Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying out the Youtube APIs, to perform simple searches and return a list of videos.

I have created a codepen [here](http://cdpn.io/tcehf).

My issue is that some of the returned URLs are like "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/WM921saJqXc/responses" while some other urls are like "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKExjoV6y2U&feature=youtube_gdata", which is ok... I guess I'm doing something wrong here.
Can you advise me or point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The best advice is to use [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). It's new (not experimental anymore), RESTful, easy to understand, and widely supported. You won't need to depend on unsupported behaviors like custom URL building etc.

[API Blog Post for more information](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/12/the-simpler-yet-more-powerful-new.html)

[Sample codes](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples) to get you started and most common uses cases in variety of languages.

Answer (score 0):

I only have the basics as am still learning the api myself, but the first is a "FEED" which will contain many things depending on the one you choose in an array . The second is a direct link to the selected video you are dealing with.

You need to look at the different feed types. Each different depending on what you are looking for.
By Author, by type, by trending, by toppic .....  Also have feeds relating to a single item like channel or video.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advices, I seem to have worked it out though, I was referring to the wrong link apparently.

I had to use

```
data.feed.entry.media$group.media$content[0].url
```

:D

Thanks again - I will look into v3 APIS though!